# Usage of と particle in this specific case

Tags: particle-と

I bumped into this sentence recently "話し手から見て、聞き手の方に より近いと意識される物事を指す。"
I was wondering whether or not the と particle before "意識される物事を指す。" is the one which marks a quotation, meaning "that".